# Query exection is failed with error ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

Tags: sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

Hi i am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-CU4)

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.PI_LOOKUP_CATEGORY_ID,  
    REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(A.LOOKUP_CATEGORY_NAME), ' ', '_'), '-', '_') AS CATEGORY_TECH_NAME, 
    A.LOOKUP_CATEGORY_NAME, 
    A.LOOKUP_CATEGORY_DESCR,
    COUNT(B.PI_LOOKUP_CATEGORY_ID) AS USAGE_COUNT
    FROM [PI_LOOKUP_CATEGORY] A LEFT OUTER JOIN [PI_INSIGHT_COLUMN] B ON 
    A.PI_LOOKUP_CATEGORY_ID = B.PI_LOOKUP_CATEGORY_ID
    GROUP BY A.PI_LOOKUP_CATEGORY_ID,  
    REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(A.LOOKUP_CATEGORY_NAME), ' ', '_'), '-', '_'), 
    A.LOOKUP_CATEGORY_NAME, 
    A.LOOKUP_CATEGORY_DESCR
    ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(A.LOOKUP_CATEGORY_NAME), ' ', '_'), '-', '_')
```

above query is failed with error "Query exection is failed with error ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."

same query is working fine with lower version of sql servers like (2008R2, 2012 etc)

please let us know the solution for this issue over SQL server 2014.

Comment: Why are you attempting to apply `DISTINCT` after group by? You have already grouped data by unique values, there is nothing more duplicating. Remove `DISTINCT`. And have a try to move calculations (all those replaces) into CTE.

Comment: My concern is, query is working fine with SQL servers like 2008 or 2012, It is not working with SQL Server 2014 (SP1), This is an issue with sql server 2014 Is there any KB or Update for this issue from Microsoft community

Comment: This is about what became deprecated, obsolete or started work different with new version. You should read _what's new_ or _howto migrate_ articles regarding recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 SELECT DISTINCT A.PI_LOOKUP_CATEGORY_ID,
             REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(A.LOOKUP_CATEGORY_NAME), ' ', ''), '-', '') AS CATEGORY_TECH_NAME, 
             A.LOOKUP_CATEGORY_NAME, A.LOOKUP_CATEGORY_DESCR, 
             COUNT(B.PI_LOOKUP_CATEGORY_ID) AS USAGE_COUNT 
FROM [PI_LOOKUP_CATEGORY] A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [PI_INSIGHT_COLUMN] B ON A.PI_LOOKUP_CATEGORY_ID = B.PI_LOOKUP_CATEGORY_ID 
GROUP BY A.PI_LOOKUP_CATEGORY_ID, 
         REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(A.LOOKUP_CATEGORY_NAME), ' ', ''), '-', ''), 
         A.LOOKUP_CATEGORY_NAME, 
         A.LOOKUP_CATEGORY_DESCR 
ORDER BY CATEGORY_TECH_NAME
```

Comment: Query is ok,
My concern is, it is working  fine with SQL servers like 2008 or 2012 
It is not working with SQL Server 2014 (SP1), This is an issue with sql server 2014
Is there any KB or Update for this issue from Microsoft community.

Comment: @user3226698: So didn't it work with `ORDER BY CATEGORY_TECH_NAME` ?

Comment: No Its not working with 'ORDER BY CATEGORY_TECH_NAME'

Comment: Note: `DISTINCT` has absolutely no sense in this query. It's impossible to get duplicates after `GROUP BY` with the identical columns list.